# error in two way communication in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am getting an error like:

> [ts] Declaration or statement expected

when I am passing elements from `child` to `parent` that is while practicing 2 way communication. I am  not getting what is the error

```js
//child 

import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
//import { Hero } from './app.hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'bro-root',
  template:` 
    <div>
      <h1>name:</h1>
      <h2>{{fname}}</h2>
      <h2>{{sname}}</h2>
      <h2 style="background-color:red;width:80px;">{{bruz}}</h2>
      <h2 style="background-color:red;width:80px;">{{no}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  })
export class ChildComponent {
  fname:string = "tom";
  sname:string = "jerry";
  gender:string = "male";
  age:number = 20;

  @Input()
  bruz:string;
  @Input()
  no:number;
  @Output()
  change:EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  this.change.emit(11);
}


//parent

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './app.childcomponent';
//import { Hero } from './app.Hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <bro-root[no]="count" (change)="updateFromChild($event)"></bro-root>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  count:number = 10;

  updateFromChild($event) {
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any good (trans/)compiler will give you the line where your error is. Also any good IDE will underline that in red. What are you coding on, paper?

Comment: So did you manage to fix your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```js
this.change.emit(11);
```

Should be in a method like the constructor of your component:

```js
export MyComponent {

  /* ... */

  constructor() {
    this.change.emit(11);
  }
}
```

You can also place it in a ngInit method like this (add the `extends` to your component):

```js
export MyComponent extends OnInit {

  /* ... */

  ngOnInit() {
    this.change.emit(11);
  }
}
```

---

Also there seems to be a typo in your second template. Make sure there is a space between `bro-root` and `[no]`:

```html
<bro-root [no]="count" (change)="updateFromChild($event)"></bro-root>
```

Comment: ya it has resolved thank you very much@Adrien Brunelat
and I am new to Angular 2

Comment: Then you should accept the answer. We'll both earn reputation.